# auth.fgx.ms error on brand new Windows 10 install

Tags: windows-10, javascript

I have a fresh install of Windows 10 (I did elect to keep files), build 17735. On the first boot, immediately after login, the following error is shown?

[image]

I know some app is running some JavaScript that has errors, but what is Windows doing here, and, more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this problem happen on a non-Windows Insider build?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry I don't have the ability to reproduce on a non-Windows Insider build